# USB charger for GoPro -- I need 5V, 2A, but does the wattage matter?

Tags: gopro

I just got a Hero 9 and an Enduro battery.  It came with a USB cable but nothing to connect that cable to the wall socket.  I had thought that I could charge it with the computer, but apparently that's not recommended, as the laptop I had wouldn't (I was told) provide enough power.  I also thought that perhaps GoPro would sell what I needed, but apparently their SuperCharger isn't available, or at least not for the Hero 9.

The GoPro site says I need something that provides 5V and 2A.  I've tried to find that, but am having difficulty.  I went to some local stores, but was told that what they had was meant for mobile phones and would provide "too high" a wattage for a GoPro, and would damage it and/or the batteries.  The components that I found -- the ones that plug into the wall socket and have a spot to plug in the USB cable -- all were something like 15 to 20W.  I have no idea what I'm looking for in terms of wattage.

I would think that GoPro would provide a complete solution for charging their batteries.  Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wattage matters - it is inextricably tied to Voltage & Amperage.

**Watts = Amps x Volts**

Standard' USB power is 5V, 500mW - which is only 0.1A.
Many computers, especially since USB-C, can negotiate with a device to provide  higher power, but on USB2 really only Apple devices generally display that ability. It was added to them with the advent of the iPad, which needs more power than a phone.

You can get a stand-alone 5v 2.1A [10W] charger from just about anywhere these days, even supermarkets. it is a very common spec & should provide plenty of power for most devices.

It is not in any way 'dangerous' to have a higher Amperage in a supply than needed for the device. Amps are 'pulled' by the device, not 'pushed' by the charger.

Comment: Thanks -- but if it doesn't matter to have a higher amperage, does it matter to have a higher wattage?  That is, if it's 5V, would a higher amperage and higher wattage be OK, because it's a "current draw" situation, as you describe?

Comment: You can't do one without the other, as already explained. If voltage is your constant, the other two follow the equation.

Comment: Thanks.  What equation?  Ohm's law (V = IR), or another?

Comment: The one in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I see it now.